# Want to know where my PEAR should be installed and where it is located

Tags: php, wampserver, pear

Am actually in need to achieve converting integers into words in my application and i ran into the use of Pear but i seems not to understand what exactly they want me to do because where i got the information (http://www.techrepublic.com/article/converting-numbers-to-words-in-php/) assumes that its is already set in my computer. So please i need a clear guide on how to set it up in my server. I run WAMP (Apache version 2.4.4/Php version 5.4.16).

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php

Comment: it should be there in phpinfo() output!

Answer (score 1):

***How to install PEAR on a WAMPServer PHP Version***

Create a new folder called PEAR below the folder containing the version  of PHP you want to install PEAR extension into. eg `c:\wamp\bin\php\php.x.y.z\PEAR`   ( I like a UPPER case name here but it does not have to be that way )

If the file `go-pear.phar` does not exist in the `php.x.y.z` folder, get go-pear.phar from  `http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`, and save it into the `php.x.y.z` folder, the version you are using and want to download to.

Then you have to make sure you have the php.exe file on the windows PATH
**We do not want to do this permanantly as that would mess up WAMPServers ability to switch PHP versions at the click of a button** So ignore any suggestions you may see, to put this on your actual Windows PATH environment variable permanantly.

So from the command line either do this :

```
path=%path%;c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z

( change x and y and z to the version numbers of your PHP )
```

Alternatively, I use a batch file which I save into a folder that is already on my windows path, lets call it phppath.bat and I add this to that file

```
path=%path%;c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z;
php -v
```

You can then start a command window anytime you like and just keyin >phppath and I have access to the php.exe in any folder I may wish to code up and run some php CLI source code.

Now from a command window make sure you are in `wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` and then keyin

```
CD \wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11
php go-pear.phar

Are you installing a system-wide PEAR or a local copy?
(system|local) [system] : l
Please confirm local copy by typing 'yes' : yes

Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\tmp
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\tmp
 4. Binaries directory                            : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear
 6. Documentation directory                       : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\docs
 7. Data directory                                : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\www
10. Tests directory                               : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear.ini
12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue:
Beginning install...
Configuration written to D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear.ini...
Initialized registry...
Preparing to install...
installing phar://c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.11/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Archive_Tar-1.3.7.tar...
installing phar://c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.11/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Console_Getopt-1.3.0.tar...
installing phar://c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.11/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/PEAR-1.9.4.tar...
installing phar://c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.11/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tar...
installing phar://c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.11/PEAR/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/XML_Util-1.2.1.tar...
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Tar-1.3.7
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Console_Getopt-1.3.0
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Structures_Graph-1.0.4
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.2.1
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.9.4
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)
PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"

******************************************************************************
WARNING!  The include_path defined in the currently used php.ini does not
contain the PEAR PHP directory you just specified:
<c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear>
If the specified directory is also not in the include_path used by
your scripts, you will have problems getting any PEAR packages working.


Would you like to alter php.ini <c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\php.ini>? [Y/n] : n

Please look over your php.ini file to make sure
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear is in your include_path.
Current include path           : .;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\PEAR
Configured directory           : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear
Currently used php.ini (guess) : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\php.ini
Press Enter to continue:

** WARNING! Old version found at c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11, please remove it or be sure to use the new c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear.bat command
```

The 'pear' command is now at your service at c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11\pear.bat

***TEST THAT IS WORKS***

```
>pear
```

Should show you something like this

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11>pear
Commands:
build                  Build an Extension From C Source
bundle                 Unpacks a Pecl Package
channel-add            Add a Channel
channel-alias          Specify an alias to a channel name
channel-delete         Remove a Channel From the List
channel-discover       Initialize a Channel from its server
channel-info           Retrieve Information on a Channel
channel-login          Connects and authenticates to remote channel server
channel-logout         Logs out from the remote channel server
channel-update         Update an Existing Channel
clear-cache            Clear Web Services Cache
config-create          Create a Default configuration file
config-get             Show One Setting
config-help            Show Information About Setting
config-set             Change Setting
config-show            Show All Settings
convert                Convert a package.xml 1.0 to package.xml 2.0 format
cvsdiff                Run a "cvs diff" for all files in a package
cvstag                 Set CVS Release Tag
download               Download Package
download-all           Downloads each available package from the default channel
info                   Display information about a package
install                Install Package
list                   List Installed Packages In The Default Channel
list-all               List All Packages
list-channels          List Available Channels
list-files             List Files In Installed Package
list-upgrades          List Available Upgrades
login                  Connects and authenticates to remote server [Deprecated in favor of channel-login]
logout                 Logs out from the remote server [Deprecated in favor of channel-logout]
makerpm                Builds an RPM spec file from a PEAR package
package                Build Package
package-dependencies   Show package dependencies
package-validate       Validate Package Consistency
pickle                 Build PECL Package
remote-info            Information About Remote Packages
remote-list            List Remote Packages
run-scripts            Run Post-Install Scripts bundled with a package
run-tests              Run Regression Tests
search                 Search remote package database
shell-test             Shell Script Test
sign                   Sign a package distribution file
svntag                 Set SVN Release Tag
uninstall              Un-install Package
update-channels        Update the Channel List
upgrade                Upgrade Package
upgrade-all            Upgrade All Packages [Deprecated in favor of calling upgrade with no parameters]
Usage: pear [options] command [command-options] <parameters>
Type "pear help options" to list all options.
Type "pear help shortcuts" to list all command shortcuts.
Type "pear help <command>" to get the help for the specified command.


C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.11>pear list-channels
REGISTERED CHANNELS:
====================
CHANNEL      ALIAS   SUMMARY
doc.php.net  phpdocs PHP Documentation Team
pear.php.net pear    PHP Extension and Application
                     Repository
pecl.php.net pecl    PHP Extension Community Library
__uri        __uri   Pseudo-channel for static packages
```

Comment: please see my php.ini include and tell me if i got it right

Comment: include_path = "c:\php\includes;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear\PEAR"

Comment: Normally if you are using WAMPServer, everything should go under `\wamp\.....` somewhere Not sure why you have `C:\php\include` in there

Comment: currently i have reinstalled the pear again after i have deleted the earlier one i did and now i had to follow your procedure and as we speak, it worked as instructed and this is what i have in my php.ini include path; include_path = ".;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear" and thats all. I downloaded the Numbers to class module in put in pear\PEAR directory and yet it cldnt find the words.php file....Error! *crying*